# How can I round a number to the nearest number evenly divisible by 16?

Tags: php

I have a simple round function. It rounds to an even number. I want to make sure that number is divisible by 16. Anyone know an easy way to round the number to the nearest number divisible evenly by 16?

```
$num=round(480/$other_num); //will output some number.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$num = 39;
$num = round($num / 16) * 16; // 32
```

Comment: Use `floor()` if you need to always round it down (instead of nearest up or down).

Answer (score 2):

the easy way seems to be divide by 16, then use the "classical round" and multiply back by 16.

```
$num=round(480/16)*16;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can bit-and the number with 0xf and add 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
 function round16($num) {
    if ($num % 16 == 0) return $num;
    $num2 = $num;
    $remain = 0;
    do {
        $remain = --$num % 16;
    } while ($remain != 0 && $num >= $num2 - 7);
    if ($remain == 0) return $num;
    do {
        $remain = ++$num2 % 16;
    } while ($remain != 0);
    return $num2;
 }
```

Probably not the most efficient way to do it.